# Best way to migrate out of box SharePoint 2010 --> SharePoint 2016 site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-2007

I need to migrate a out of box SP2010 site to SP2016 site with 20 subsites. Could you please advise the best possible way to migrate it.

1. Backup and Restore the content DB from SP2010 --> SP2016 , since its an out of box site.
2. Perform manual migration of list,libraries,subsites using Export/Import commands and recreating in SP2016 site.
3. Using Sharegate tool to migrate

Looking forward to hear from you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using Sharegate tool to migrate is something I can give my vote too